# How to make animation completed after active selector

Tags: css, sass

I've had problems with my animation on :active selector. I'm not a CSS guru, so I don't know if there is any shorthand solution on this. For example:

```
.actionButton{
    &:active, &:focus{
        animation: activeButton 2.5s alternate infinite ease-in;
    }
}

@keyframes activeButton{
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    50% {transform: rotate(90deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(120deg);}
}
```

As you can see I have an animaton that should last 2.5 seconds on active selector. When the user actives (clicks) the button animation starts as expected, but after very short period of time as the active selector removes, the animation also immediately stops. So animaton plays way more shorter than I expect. How can I guarantee that animation plays and completes its period of 2.5 seconds at least once?

Comment: I don't think you can with just css. You can do it with a little javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing, In your Javascript, set an `event listener` for the `button` when it is `active`, and there using `style` property set the `animation` property when it is `active` (means when it is clicked). So, a click event and within the event listener add the below property.

```
animation: activeButton 2.5s alternate infinite ease-in;
```

Something like below:

**JS :**

```
document.querySelector(".actionButton").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    this.style.animation="activeButton 2.5s alternate infinite ease-in";
});
```

Comment: It's so sad that we can't configure it on CSS.

Comment: I think we can but in a rough way which would not be a good option, We may need to add a `hover` there also, because `active`  technically means you clicked and left. So, till the time you press down and your animation holds (small time that you are talking about). 
In Javascript, we are specifically telling it look for a click event and start our animation for 2.5s :)

Comment: Seems you are from Turkey, Respect :) 
Do one think, Create a codepen project and share the link with me but I am occupied with work today and tomorrow. On Saturday I may have a look into this InshaAllah :)

Comment: Haha respect to Pakistan and I hope you are happy! Thank you but I can do it myself.